# Android send Stripe token and card data to server

Tags: php, android, stripe-payments

i am trying to integrate Stripe for getting payments in my Android app and i can successfully generate Stripe Token for a given Credit Card. My problem is when i send a Post request using Volley so that the card could be charged. I am using a PHP code for making the credit card charge.
I am getting the following error when i do the POST request: E/Volley: [295] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500

My php code for doing the charge:

```
<?php

require_once('stripe-php/init.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('MY API KEY');

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form

$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$type = $_POST['type'];

$name = $_POST['name'];

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card

try {

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(

"amount" => $amount,

"currency" => "usd",

"source" => $token,)

);

//email the purcahse and code info to your email


// create a json output with completion variable, (this will be read from the ios app as response)

$json = array(

'completion' => 'done'

);

echo json_encode($json);

} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

// The card has been declined

$errorMessage = $e->getMessage();

$json = array(

'completion' => $errorMessage

);

echo json_encode($json);

}

?>
```

Volley request:

```
public void postPayment (final Token token, final String url) {



        try {
            final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();

            jsonBody.put("stripeToken", token.getId());
            jsonBody.put("amount", "200");
            jsonBody.put("name", "Ali Akkawi");
            jsonBody.put("type", "mytype");


            final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            StringRequest sendRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,  new Response.Listener<String>() {



            @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.i(TAG, response.toString());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }) {




                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() {

                    try {

                        return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {

                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }

//                @Override
//                public String getBodyContentType() {
//
//                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
//                }


            };



            Volley.newRequestQueue(PaymentActivity.this).add(sendRequest);

        }catch (Exception e) {


            e.printStackTrace();

}

}
```

Comment: It looks like the page is returning a 500 error, which means there is a problem with your PHP script. If you can access the page directly via a browser do you receive an error message, or are there any errors in the webserver logs? The PHP syntax looks fine so an error message would be the best place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, i use the same php file with my ios app and it is working fine, i think the problem is with one of the parameters iam sending from Android, i tried a lot but i couldnt find the issue

Comment: Then I would hazard a guess that you are missing a parameter, one of: `name`, `type`, `amount` or `stripeToken`. You should probably add some validation to your PHP script that checks the POST'ed values exist and are valid and return the results of the validation on error. That'll help you discern what is going on.